# How to take screenshot from Panel in mono C#?

Tags: winforms, mono

How to take all screenshot from Panel in mono C# ?
I need not used winAPI.

My panel can not be fully visible.

Comment: You want to take a screenshot of *just* your panel? Does Mono support the `Control.DrawToBitmap` method?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question is not exactly clear but in case you meant taking a screenshot of the desktop: below is a small example of how you could do this using gtk:

```
using Gtk;

...

Gdk.Window window = Gdk.Global.DefaultRootWindow;
if (window!=null)
{           
    Gdk.Pixbuf pixBuf = new Gdk.Pixbuf(Gdk.Colorspace.Rgb, false, 8, 
                                   window.Screen.Width, window.Screen.Height);          
    pixBuf.GetFromDrawable(window, Gdk.Colormap.System, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
                           window.Screen.Width, window.Screen.Height);          
    pixBuf.ScaleSimple(400, 300, Gdk.InterpType.Bilinear);
    pixBuf.Save("screenshot0.jpeg", "jpeg");
}
```

hope this helps, regards